# Button OnClick Event shows error while compiling

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

ERROR : Method 'Protected WithEvents login As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub EventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)'.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login with FaceBook" OnClick="Login" />

Protected Sub Login(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        FaceBookConnect.Authorize("user_photos,email", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split("?"c)(0))
        Try
            Dim str1 As String = "INSERT INTO users (ID, DP, displayName) values('" + lblId.Text + "', '" + ProfileImage.ImageUrl.ToString + "', '" + lblName.Text + "')"
            Dim str2 As MySqlDataReader
            Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            command.CommandText = str1
            command.Connection = con
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            con.Open()
            str2 = command.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't bean issue at all. I am guessing that probably you have defined a class named as `EventArgs`. Change the signature to

```
Protected Sub Login(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
```